# Regression help

Tags: regression

I am doing a medical study for my thesis concerning the number of organs a donor (numbers ranging from from 0-7) will produce given certain circumstances. I am monitoring their blood sugar, ejection fraction, etc (which are whole numbers) but I also have categorical figures such as Race, Gender, etc. On top of that, I have some yes or no questions as well. I can convert these to binary numbers, but would that mess up a multiple regression or give me bad results. Should I look into another model?

Comment: Depending on the amount of data, I would build multiple regression models depending on the different binary categories.  (i.e. Male, White gets a curve, Female White gets a curve...etc.)  Mixtures of regression and discrimination models can often simplify tough problems. An analogy would be building a dog house, you can't just use a hammer.  You need multiple tools. Of course this is only one way to do it and am sure others will have some good advice on converting to a strict regression model so would try various techniques and see which fits your data and experience the best.

Comment: Should I also look into generalized linear models?

Comment: no. of organs a donor will produce ? explain

Comment: I can explain more. So we are studying a few factors that could increase the number of organs we can recover from a donor. In the end, a donor can produce 0 organs up to 7. So this is my dependent variable. I have about 15 independent variables, some being things like age, race, sex, BMI, to more advanced medical things.

Comment: What is your sample size?  Can you post a histogram of the outcome variable?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_UMKyJA6LKdqNi5KQpcceWZ00HDuL65WX3TUuUTFbMM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sure you can try it, but you are still trying to use a continuum model to fit a discrete variable.  If you build two linear models, one for men, one for women, you basically get the same effect with two simpler models opposed to one complicated model.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for might be an ordinal logistic regression. The outcome variable takes a small number of discrete values that have a defined order. The predictor variables can be continuous, binary, categorical, etc., as for standard linear regression. [This page](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm) gives examples; searches on the name will provide more. This is a type of generalized linear model. In general, a single model including all predictor variables will be better than several parallel models for different groups, as you will have better pooled estimates of the residual error around the fit and more degrees of freedom for statistical tests.

As a student working on a thesis, you presumably have access to a local statistics department. From the nature of parts of your question (for example, wondering if binary predictor variables will "mess up" a regression, which they will not) it seems that you do not have a lot of experience with regression analysis and statistics. Look for and get some local help to ensure that the statistically based parts of your thesis meet professional standards.

With your data, such statistical help will be particularly important for dealing with the large number of missing data points on ejection fraction. If you wish to include that as a predictor, you will have to do imputation of the missing data or else regression software will remove cases without values for that variable. Handling imputations properly with the preferred multiple imputation methods can take some expertise and experience.

Comment: @A.Romain, note that the binomial regression suggested in the other answer could also be useful, depending on your assumptions about the processes underlying the differences in organ yield. You might also want to consider whether you should be treating all the organs independently. For example, I suspect that if you can harvest one kidney successfully you are very likely to harvest both. Those types of issues would best be discussed with competent local statistical advisers.

Comment: That's a good thought! You are right that both kidneys would probably be recovered as compared to one. What could I do in this situation? Simply list it as one instead of two so then my max number of recoverable organs be 6 instead of 7?  I looked into ucla's guide to ordinal regression from the following site and it makes a lot of sense. Thanks again for all of the help! http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/dae/ologit.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could treat it as a binomial variable with the number of organs out of 7. In Stata, it would look like:
glm y x1 x2 ... , fam(bin 10) link(logit) robust